# Prove that $|\log(1 + x^2) - \log(1 + y^2)| \le |x-y|$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I need to show that $ \forall x,y \in \mathbb R, |\log(1 + x^2) - \log(1 + y^2)| \le |x-y|$

I tried using concavity of log function: $\log(1 + x^2) - \log(1 + y^2)=\log(\frac{1 + x^2}{1 + y^2})=\log(\frac{x^2y^2}{(1 + y^2)y^2}+\frac{1}{1 + y^2}) \ge \frac{2(\log(x)-\log(y))}{1+y^2}$

Also the middle value theorem: $0<\frac{\log(1 + x^2) - \log(1 + y^2)}{x^2-y^2} <1$

But both attempts has not led too far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derivative of $f(x)=\log(1+x^2)$ is
$$
f'(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}
$$
and
$$
\left|\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right|\le1
$$
because
$$
2|x|\le 1+|x|^2
$$
since
$$
(1-|x|)^2\ge0
$$

Thus, by the mean value theorem,
$$
\frac{\log(1+x^2)-\log(1+y^2)}{x-y}=f'(z)
$$
for $z$ between $x$ and $y$ (assuming $x\ne y$ or the inequality is obvious). Then
$$
\left|\frac{\log(1+x^2)-\log(1+y^2)}{x-y}\right|=|f'(z)|\le 1
$$

Comment: (+1) My answer was very similar to yours, but you were a minute faster than I, so I deleted mine...

Answer (score 0):

HINT: using the mean value theorem for the function $$f(t)=\ln(1+t^2)$$ we get
$$f(x)-f(y)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}(x-y)$$ and we have $$\left|\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right|\le 1$$

Answer (score 0):

We can write the term of interest as

$$\left|\log(1+x^2)=\log(1+y^2)\right|=\left|\int_y^x \frac{2t}{1+t^2}\,dt\right|$$

Now, the integrand $f(t)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ attains its maximum value of $1$ when $t=1$.  Therefore, the inequality follows immediately from the mean value theorem.

Comment: @micep It might be even more efficient to use the MVT for integrals.  ;-)) - Mark